# Why javax.mail packages in google app engine sdk?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I can find javax.mail packages in google app engine sdk. Can anyone tell me the purpose of including such packages in google app engine where we already have a dedicated jar ( java mail) for these packages in market.

Answer (score 0):

Control of the environment. When the JavaMail API is provided it allows GAE to control what mail server and javamail providers are used for sending and receiving.

From the [Overview of Sockets API for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/):

> Sockets are only available for paid apps, and traffic from sockets is billed as outgoing bandwidth.
>   [snip]
>   Port 25 (SMTP) is blocked;

The GAE javax.mail API provides email to free GAE accounts where as if you had to include a jar you would have to get a paid GAE account to send or receive email.